# NodeJS/Puppeteer - Change URL

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape a page that needs login

Then, I need to go to another page. I can't click, so I tried to change the url

It works when I dot it manually, but when I use page.goto it just logs off

**So, how could I change current URL? And why it doesn't work with page.goto**

I can't post system url, but i did something like that:

```
const baseURL = 'www.example.com'
await page.goto(baseURL)
...login code...
const pageIWannaGo = '/dir/page.html'
await page.goto(baseURL + pageIWannaGo)
```

But it just logs off, and it works when i do it manually

Comment: Not sure if it's a TYPO but... it should be `page.goto(baseURL)` and `page.goto(baseURL + pageIWannaGo)`

Comment: yes, it was a typo...

Comment: Are you sending any extra header when redirecting manually?

Answer (score 2):

Base on a document about function **goto** from [puppeteer](http://const%20baseURL%20=%20'www.example.com'%20page.goto(baseURL)%20...login%20code...%20const%20pageIWannaGo%20=%20'/dir/page.html'%20page.goto(baseURL%20+%20pageIWannaGo)). Try this code

```
const baseURL = 'www.example.com'
await page.goto(baseURL)
...login code...
const pageIWannaGo = '/dir/page.html'
await page.goto(baseURL + pageIWannaGo)
```

Comment: yes, but it does not work cause when I log the url changes. So page.url() returns www.example.com/logged

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the function, most (all?) of puppeteer functions are async.

```
await page.goto(myURL);
```